# Jquery change event not firing on chrome in mac only. Works on safari, firefox, and on chrome on windows 7

Tags: jquery, ajax, macos, events, google-chrome

The change event is not even firing on mac chromes.  Works for win7 on chrome, firefox, and ie, also works on firefox and safari on mac.  But not on chrome.  Any ideas?  Thanks

edit: its a drop down menu... Its basically a state/city chooser, where i load the cities based on the chosen state from the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#cod_estados').change(function(){
                if( $(this).val() ) {
                    $('#cod_cidades').hide();
                    $('.carregando').show();
                    $.getJSON('cidades-ajax.php?search=',{cod_estados: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
                        var options = '<option value=""></option>'; 
                        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                            options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_cidades + '">' + j[i].nome + '</option>';
                        }   
                        $('#cod_cidades').html(options).show();
                        $('.carregando').hide();
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#cod_cidades').html('<option value="">â€“ Escolha um estado â€“</option>');
                }
            });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: is #cod_estados is an id of a textbox or dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.  It was inside a facebook App.

I was accessing jquery from the googleapi links which was not a secure URL.  Chrome on macs for some reason block the connection.  Putting JQuery in a secure server solved the issue.